# How do I make a dot plot with a continuous x-axis (ggplot2)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm trying to create a vertically oriented double plot with a line plot above and dot plot below, with both on the same (continuous, date) x-axis.  I've successfully placed the two plots on a common axis and finished the (upper) line plot, but when I try to change the (lower) dot plot's x-axis from categorical to continuous, all my dots bunch up in the middle of the plot.

I only include here my code for the dot plot for simplicity, but if it turns out I need to show you the full double plot, I can do that.

Here's a small subset of my data, then my code, as far as I've gotten with it:

```
data <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                               1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                               2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L
), .Label = c("11/11/2016", "12/16/2016", "12/2/2016", "12/23/2016"
), class = "factor"), factor = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
                                 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), temp = c(-19.85, -19.94, -20.77, -21.3, -21.71, -21.88, -22.03, 
            -22.74, -22.86, -18.88, -19.02, -19.22, -19.32, -19.32, -19.55, 
            -19.68, -20.23, -20.32, -21.37, -16.63, -19.01, -19.67, -20.47, 
            -21.14, -21.23, -23.01, -24.43, -24.61, -24.76, -15.9, -18.87, 
            -19.02, -19.16, -19.44, -19.62, -22.38, -24.37, -24.92, -26.9
)), .Names = c("date", "factor", "temp"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                              -39L))


library(ggplot2)
library(scales)


#format date and order date levels (the second line here gives me a warning, but seems to do what I want it to)..
data$date <- as.Date(data$date, "%m/%d/%Y")
data$date.chr <- factor(data$date, as.character(data$date))
data$date.chr <- as.Date(data$date.chr)


#now plot..
ggplot(data, aes(x = date.chr, fill = factor(factor), y = temp)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = 'y', stackdir = 'center', method = 'histodot', binwidth = 0.3, position=position_dodge(0.8)) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 weeks", labels = date_format("%e %b"), limits = as.Date(c("2016-11-04","2016-12-23"))) +
  labs(title="", x="", y="response temp (°C)") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=1)) +
  theme(legend.position="top") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=10)))
```

(My session info:
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1)

Any suggestions how I can (dot) plot this data on a continuous x-axis?  (again, so I can line it up with the date axis in a plot above it)

Comment: `scale_x_date` is a continuous scale. Or do you mean you need to actually use `scale_x_continuous`?

Comment: Axeman:  I don't know, but am open to suggestions.  The code above does create a continuous scale, but doesn't plot the data in the way I'm aiming for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but let's see:

```
data$date <- as.Date(data$date, "%m/%d/%Y")
data$date.chr <- factor(data$date)
#create dummy variable to get both the position and "filling" right
data$datefact <- paste(data$factor,data$date.chr)
```

The trick here is to set the "group" argument in `geom_dotplot` to the dummy variable created before:

```
    ggplot(data, aes(x = date, y = temp)) +
  # geom_point() + 
  geom_dotplot(aes(x = date, group = datefact, fill = factor(factor)),binaxis = 'y', 
               stackdir = 'center',
               method = 'histodot', 
               binwidth = 0.3)+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 weeks", labels = date_format("%e %b"), limits = as.Date(c("2016-11-04","2016-12-23"))) +
  labs(title="", x="", y="response temp (°C)") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=1)) +
  theme(legend.position="top") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=10)))
```

giving:

[image]

Is this what you wanted ?

Comment: LoBu: This helps.. but there's still something I don't quite understand yet going on here.  When I tried this on my full dataset, including the factor made the dot plot groupings too complicated to look at.  When I omitted the factor and just used "date" in the grouping, the placement of the dots within date groupings changed visibly and become symmetrical (which looks more right to me).  I'm not quite sure what setting(s) of the dot plot is/are affected here.  I think if you tried this on the small example here, the dots would become symmetrical.  Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: The placement of the dots "moved", I think, because if you change the grouping the "distribution statistics" used to make the dotplot change. That, in addition to `position_dodge` led probably to the asymmetrical plots. Just removing `position_dodge` gives the plot in the edited answer. Is that ok ? Consider that if you keep only `date` in the grouping, the dotplot will not take into account the differences between your factor levels distributions.

Comment: LoBu:  Right!  `position_dodge` was mistakenly carried over from a previous code where I had a different grouping structure.  In any case, once I tweaked the dodge value, I got the groups separated enough to see them clearly.  Thank you for your help.. I'm still learning this language.